# Is there any way I can use li:first-child and li:hover

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I have a different background image for the first and last child of a navigation built with `<li>`s.

I also want to add hover image. Is there any way I can add `:first-child` and `:hover` together?

```
#nav li:first-child{
background:url(../images/topnavsprite.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#nav li:first-child:hover{
background:url(../images/topnavsprite.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got it already. Might just need to adjust your background-position if you're doing sprite to get the right portion of your image on hover, or on first-child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you’ve got it already.

- `#nav li:first-child` selects the first `<li>`
- `#nav li:first-child:hover` selects the first `<li>` when it’s hovered

Ditto for `last-child`. (In browsers that support `first-child`, `last-child`, and `:hover` on elements that aren’t links, so earlier versions of Internet Explorer may well have trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me.

```
li:first-child:hover, li:last-child:hover {...}
```